# Is there a way to force stop an SQL query in Query Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud

When using Query Studio, is there a way to force stop a query after 'Run' has been clicked? E.g. if I spot a mistake as soon as I click 'Run' or if the query is taking >15 minutes and I want to cancel and try again?

I'm assuming that closing the browser tab doesn't actually stop the query it just hides it from view.

Comment: For any query of substance, it's better to manually create a target DE and add a Query Activity in an Automation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query Studio does nothing proprietary. It actually sends an API call to create a Query Activity, which you can find in automation studio under activities, with an autogenerated name ("interactivequery-[MID]-[somethingUnique]"). It then starts this activity via API.

Looking at that query, you can also see how query studio takes a couple shortcuts to be less error prone.

You can then interact with this activity like with any other. Can you stop it  from running? Not to my knowledge, at least the "action log" tab is always empty and I've never seen a use for it with any query activity, with or without query studio. I always place my activities in an automation to get these controls (view a log, interrupt it...). Since query studio does not, the answer is probably no.

You can of course delete this query activity it by hitting the trash can - will that interrupt it from running? Unclear, likely yes. Is that important - probably not.

if the query runs, then it will populate an autogenerated DE, which auto-deletes after 24 hours anyway. Your next query will create its own, so there is no conflict.

As a sidenote.
Closing the window in query studio indeed does nothing to this activity, so indeed it wont stop it from executing. However, it allows you to start anew and will create a separate query activity & DE next time you hit "run", - of course all this runs on the same database, so there is a theoretical performance impact but ONE concurrent query will not have a noticeable impact on another. If you do this thousands of times, something might feel slower indeed.